# AWS S3 list bucket objects request authentication using query parameters

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, httr

I am following the instructions outlined in the AWS S3 API documentation to authenticate requests using query parameters:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

The block of code below will successfully return the listing of all keys from the given bucket.

```
library(digest)
library(httr)
library(RCurl)

Sys.setenv(TZ="Greenwich")
ts <- strftime(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
d <- strftime(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%d')

bucket <- 'my-bucket'

credentials <- paste(Sys.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY'),d,'us-east-1','s3','aws4_request',sep='/')

request <- paste('GET\n/\nX-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
               '&X-Amz-Credential=',curlEscape(credentials),
               '&X-Amz-Date=',ts,
               '&X-Amz-Expires=60',
               '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host\n',
               'host:',bucket,'.s3.amazonaws.com\n\n',
               'host\n',
               'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
               sep='')

request.digest <- digest(request,algo='sha256',serialize=FALSE)
string.to.sign <- paste('AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n',
                      ts,'\n',
                      d,'/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n',
                      request.digest,sep='')

sig <- hmac(paste('AWS4',Sys.getenv('AWS_SECRET_KEY'),sep=''),d,algo='sha256',raw=TRUE)
sig <- hmac(sig,'us-east-1',algo='sha256',raw=TRUE)
sig <- hmac(sig,'s3',algo='sha256',raw=TRUE)
sig <- hmac(sig,'aws4_request',algo='sha256',raw=TRUE)
sig <- hmac(sig,string.to.sign,algo='sha256')

response <- GET(paste('https://',bucket,'.s3.amazonaws.com?',
                    'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
                    '&X-Amz-Credential=',curlEscape(credentials),
                    '&X-Amz-Date=',ts,
                    '&X-Amz-Expires=60',
                    '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host',
                    '&X-Amz-Signature=',sig,
                    sep=''))
```

The above works fine but it isn't really feasible for me to return all keys located in an S3 bucket. I would like to add a prefix parameter to only return matching keys. However, there is a problem when I try to add in a prefix parameter to limit the key results returned by the request.

In the documentation it gives the following example GET request as a way to return a more limited result set of keys in a bucket

```
GET /?prefix=N&marker=Ned&max-keys=40 HTTP/1.1
Host: quotes.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Wed, 01 Mar  2006 12:00:00 GMT
Authorization: authorization string
```

Based on this, if I wanted to add prefix=m, it would seem to me that my Canonical URI would be `/?prefix=m` and I would add `prefix=m` to my Canonical Query String based on the chart link below which is found in the link at the top of this page.

[image]

Additionally, I have added the query parameter as part of the URL sent using GET() from the httr package.

I have tried several combinations of possible queries but I keep getting a 403 response from the server. Below is a sample of what I feel should work according to the documentation.

```
library(digest)
library(httr)
library(RCurl)

Sys.setenv(TZ="Greenwich")
ts <- strftime(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
d <- strftime(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%d')

bucket <- 'my-bucket'

credentials <- paste(Sys.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY'),d,'us-east-1','s3','aws4_request',sep='/')

request <- paste('GET\n/?prefix=m\n',
             'prefix=m',
             '&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
             '&X-Amz-Credential=',curlEscape(credentials),
             '&X-Amz-Date=',ts,
             '&X-Amz-Expires=60',
             '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host\n',
             'host:',bucket,'.s3.amazonaws.com\n\n',
             'host\n',
             'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
             sep='')

request.digest <- digest(request,algo='sha256',serialize=FALSE)
string.to.sign <- paste('AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n',
                    ts,'\n',
                    d,'/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n',
                    request.digest,sep='')

sig <- hmac(paste('AWS4',Sys.getenv('AWS_SECRET_KEY'),sep=''),d,algo='sha256',raw=TRUE)
sig <- hmac(sig,'us-east-1',algo='sha256',raw=TRUE)
sig <- hmac(sig,'s3',algo='sha256',raw=TRUE)
sig <- hmac(sig,'aws4_request',algo='sha256',raw=TRUE)
sig <- hmac(sig,string.to.sign,algo='sha256')

response <- GET(paste('https://',bucket,'.s3.amazonaws.com?',
                  'prefix=m',
                  '&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
                  '&X-Amz-Credential=',curlEscape(credentials),
                  '&X-Amz-Date=',ts,
                  '&X-Amz-Expires=60',
                  '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host',
                  '&X-Amz-Signature=',sig,
                  sep=''))
```

I am still receiving this message from the server after running the code above:

```
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Does anyone have experience using the S3 API with R that can shed some light on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have a package called [**aws.signature**](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.signature) that can calculate these signatures for you. And, we're actively developing [an S3 client called **aws.s3**](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3). Both will probably be helpful whether you decide to pursue your own client or just use ours. Both are on CRAN as of April 2017.